# Mapping to Dictionary collection in PetaPoco?

Tags: c#-4.0, petapoco

way to map the following to a Dictionary??

```
Sql sql = new Sql()
.Append("SELECT Count(*) ")
.Append("FROM Custumers")
.Append("WHERE CustomerId = @0", Id)

var result = database.Fetch<Dictionary<int,DateTime>>(sql);
```

I cannot use List as DateTime is also thr.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Petapoco always return a `List<T>`, but you can convert the List to a Dictionary afterwards:

```
var result = database
    .Fetch<Pair<int,DateTime>>(sql)
    .ToDictionary(i => i.ID, i => i.Date);
```

Comment: What is  Pair in this case?  KeyValuePair does not work

Comment: For anyone else that is reading this and is wondering what a Pair is, it looks like it's a generic class that was inspired by the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13646110/3830432

Answer (score 6):

With NPoco you can write this: it will use the first 2 columns

```
var result = database.Dictionary<int, DateTime>(sql);
```

or use what @Eduardo said.